# Not getting how to queue the animation sequesnce

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am working on a small script. I am almost done, there is just little modifications need to done. See the [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nW5JW/1/). 
  What i want to do is, only one box should say "Hello friends", but if you click 2-3 boxes immediately it shows "hello friends" in more than one boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".main").click(function(){

  if($('.active').length){
    // Slide down previous theater 
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=0',
    }, 200, function() {
        $(".main").removeClass("active");
    });     
    $(".active").next("div").animate({
        top: '+=270',
    }, 200, function() {
    }); 
  }

    // slide up new theater
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-=0',
    }, 200, function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });     
     $(this).next("div").animate({
        top: '-=270',
    }, 200, function() {
    }); 

});
});
```

Comment: [`clearQueue`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue), [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop), [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to protect against fast clicks that happen during an animation, then you probably need to use `.stop(true, true)` to stop any existing animations before you start your next animation.  This guarantees that it is in a consistent state before you start the next animation.

Once I add the `.stop(true, true)` to each of your animations here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uquB3/, then quick clicks can no longer confuse it.

---

Also, an animation of `top: '+=0'` or `top: '-=0'` does nothing.  You're telling jQuery to get the current value of top and add `0` to it which has no visible result.

Perhaps you mean to take out the `+=` and just  use `top: 0` or you don't need that animation at all?

Comment: What a nice explanation. It looks great. I just learned animation method so i was not still clear with its features.